# TFS Get all build definitions

Tags: c#, tfs

Good afternoon, I was scrolling here, reading questions and trying different code on how to get builds and all the definitions from them, however, whenever I try to execute code and get builds definitions it returns nothing, even though I for sure know there are both successful and unsuccessful builds in there. However I get nothing.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("MyUsername", "MyPassword");
        VssBasicCredential basicCred = new VssBasicCredential(credential);

        TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://tomheza.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"), basicCred);

        tpc.Authenticate();

        CatalogNode catalogNode = tpc.CatalogNode;
        ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = tpc.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject }, false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

        foreach (CatalogNode collectionNode in collectionNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(collectionNode.Resource.DisplayName);
        }

        var buildServer = (IBuildServer)tpc.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
        var vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        var teamProjects = vcs.GetAllTeamProjects(true);

        foreach (TeamProject proj in teamProjects)
        {
            var defs = buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions(proj.Name);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Team Project: {0}", proj.Name));

            foreach (IBuildDefinition def in defs)
            {
                IBuildDetailSpec spec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(proj.Name, def.Name);
                spec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 1;
                spec.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;

                var builds = buildServer.QueryBuilds(spec);

                if (builds.Builds.Length > 0)
                {
                    var buildDetail = builds.Builds[0];

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("   {0} - {1} - {2}", def.Name, buildDetail.Status.ToString(), buildDetail.FinishTime));
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

I am using VS2017 community version

Comment: Turns out getAllTeamProjects returns 0 of them.

Comment: This API only works for XAML build definitions, if you're using build vNext (default in TFS 2015+) you have to use the REST API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the comment said above, the VNext build definition information couldn't be reached using the old version API. Install this [TFS ExtendedClient Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) package for your project, using the method below to get all build definitions.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Operations;

        public static void GetBuild()
        {
            var u = new Uri("http://servername:8080/tfs/MyCollection/");
            VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("v-tinmo", "123456.w", "fareast")));
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(u, c);

            BuildHttpClient buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();

            //get all build definitions in your team projects
            List<BuildDefinitionReference> builddefs = buildServer.GetDefinitionsAsync(project:"team project name").Result;   
            foreach (BuildDefinitionReference builddef in builddefs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(builddef.Name);
                ...
            }

            //get all builds information in your team projects
            var builds = buildServer.GetBuildsAsync(project: "team project name").Result;
            foreach (var build in builds)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(build.Definition.Name + "--" + build.BuildNumber + "--" +build.Result);
            }

        }
```

You could also use t[his kind of REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-list-of-build-definitions) to get build definitions:

```
Http method: GET

http://v-tinmo-12r2:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/teamprojectname/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=2.0
```

Comment: However I am struggling to get a status of the build. Is it possible using this way?

Comment: @TomasŽemgulys I have update my code, please have a try.